# not able to target on max-width 360px

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm working on a responsive website.
The logo image size will change as of on different screen size devices

the html part

```
<div class="logo responsive-img">
    <img id="logo-header" src="assets/img/logo2.png" alt="logo" />
</div>
```

the media css

```
@media (max-width: 360px) {
    /*Logo*/
    .responsive-img {
       background-image: url(../img/logo-320.png);
       width:200px !important;
       height:28px !important;
    }
    .responsive-img img {
            display:none;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) { 
            /*Logo*/
    .responsive-img {
       background-image: url(../img/logo-mobile.png);
       width:300px !important;
       height:42px !important;
    }
    .responsive-img img {
            display:none;
    }
}
```

I tested it on local desktop browser, chrome and firefox. When browser resized to 480 the logo image replaced. However when browser keep going resize to 360, the logo img won't change.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

Move your 480px media above the 360px media.

**Long answer**

That's because order of occurrence matters in css. If two rules have the same specificity and they both define the same properties, the one that comes after will override the one that comes before.

```
.apple {
    color:red;  //this gets applied first
}

.apple {
    color:blue;  //this gets applied second, which overrides the first
}
```

The same applies to media queries. In your case all your defined properties and rules are the same.

It works above 360px because the 360px media doesn't get applied and the 480px media does.

Your 360px media does work at 360px. It just so happens that your 480px media comes after it and also gets applied since the screen width is in fact less than 480px. So the 480px media will override the same properties that your 360px media defines.